# Converting rational equations into polynomial equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

A question on my practice exam asks to solve the equation:
$$
\frac{1}{x^4} - \frac{1}{x^2} = 12
$$
In the answers section it says to first convert the equation to the equivalent equation:$$
12x^4 + x^2 - 1 = 0
$$
However, we have not yet learned how to do this and I am unable to contact my teacher before the exam next week.

So, my question is how does one convert an equation like this into a polynomial like has been achieved in this example?

Any help would be much appreciated!
Jack.

Comment: You don't have to sign your question with your name at the end, we can see who you are at the bottom right. Also, even if you have not been taught how to do this, its always good/better to at least tell is what you have tried to solve. A lot of times, it takes some of your creativity to solve problems, in maths and the real world. What have you tried? Why has it failed? Lets see if we can fix your math intuition so that you become a better self sufficient math solver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate all the fractions in a single step, just multiply each term in the equation by the LCM of all the denominators. In this case, $\text{lcm}(x^4, x^2) = x^4$, so we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x^4} - \frac{1}{x^2} &= 12 \\
x^4 \cdot \frac{1}{x^4} - x^4 \cdot \frac{1}{x^2} &= x^4 \cdot 12 \\
1 - x^2 &= 12x^4 \\
0 &= 12x^4 + x^2 - 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a heap! That makes a lot of sense now. We have been studying the laws of indices and I was trying to apply the negative power law to not much avail, but now I can see I was looking at it the wrong way.